# Changing Friendly url format

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I need to modify URL pattern for IIS Url rewrite module and I could not come up with proper regex pattern.

I already have a rule for front end of the site:

> /[event-name] ==> show-event.aspx?event=[event-name]

I need another one for admin login page.

> /[event-name]/admin==> admin-login.aspx?event=[event-name]

But IIS gives me this option:

> /admin-login/[event-name] ==> admin-login.aspx?event={R1}

How can I change order in this regex pattern for the user friendly url format I want?

> ^admin-login/([^/]+)/?$

PS: Rewrite Maps is not an option because the event-name will be a parameter and maps are static.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using presets rather than empty rules, so at first your options are limited. You can, however, *edit* your rule and change the pattern to:

```
^([^/]+)/admin/?$
```

and keep the rewrite target (admin-login.aspx?event={R:1}). That should do the job.